# German Schengen tourist visa

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, applications

For German Schengen tourist visa, if the applicant is student, is it compulsory to submit NOC from institution?

Comment: Schengen consulates are not in the business of enforcing anybody's "objections" to someone else traveling out of their country.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there are several questions relating to NOC on TSE - from what I recall seeing, it seems VFS in India make this compulsory regardless of whether or not it’s actually a specific requirement under Schengen rules.

Answer (score 1):

I could find no statement in the German guidelines that proof is mandatory and it is not stated in the application.

However, they are required to be sure that you will leave after the granted vist.

So submitting proof would likly highten your chances of receiving the visa.